# Polyglot does not detect multiple languages

Tags: python, language-detection, polyglot

I am testing the `polyglot` package in Python to detect the languages in a mixed languages document.

I am not expecting from it the most accurate prediction but to start with the package does not return anything but one language as an answer even for texts which have 2 or 3 languages in them.

The texts which I am using have on average 20 words such as the following:

```
text = 'Je travaillais en France. Je suis tres heureux. I work in London. I grew up in Manchester.'
```

I always get something like the following - no multiple languages answer:

```
Prediction is reliable: True
Language 1: name: English     code: en       confidence:  98.0 read bytes:   682
Language 2: name: un          code: un       confidence:   0.0 read bytes:     0
Language 3: name: un          code: un       confidence:   0.0 read bytes:     0
```

It is nowhere near the [example](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Detection.html) at its docs:

```
> China (simplified Chinese: 中国; traditional Chinese: 中國),
> 
> name: English     code: en       confidence:  71.0 read bytes:   887
> name: Chinese     code: zh_Hant  confidence:  11.0 read bytes:  1755
> name: un          code: un       confidence:   0.0 read bytes:     0
```

Even though to be honest when I am running the detector with the Chinese-English example above I do get a mixed languages answer.

The code is simply the following:

```
from polyglot.detect import Detector

text = 'Je travaillais en France. Je suis tres heureux. I work in London. I grew up in Manchester.'

answer = Detector(text)

print(answer)
```

Why is this happening?

*P.S.*

*Also, in the case of detecting the language of one (even very common) word `polyglot` is pretty bad.*
*For example for the word `quantita` (which is Italian) it gives back English.*

*I know that many of the these packages can be mainly succesful when having a large text but it is surprising that they cannot even capture even these simplE words.*

*`Textblob` seems to be even good with single words but you can send a very limited number of requests to it (in both cases perhaps because it uses the Google API).*

Comment: could you please share the code?

Comment: @satishsilveri, ok but it is nothing special.

Comment: have you found solution to detect this issue or identifying multiple languages in the single Text line?

Comment: @dhirajsuvarna, apologies for the belated answer but I am not frequently here. One package was this: https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/

Answer (score 1):

Just use this approach

```
print(Detector('Your_text', quiet=True))
```

Also dont forget to download language packages.
In order to download all language packages for transliteration Mode you can use:

```
from polyglot.downloader import downloader
downloader.download("TASK:transliteration2", quiet=True)
```

To download all Modes for specific language, simply run this command from terminal:

```
polyglot download LANG:ar
```

I suggest to read complete manual on downloading Modes and language packs here:
https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Download.html

Answer (score 0):

I think Polyglot detect the language by reading the characters used in the text.
The examples you have mentioned above are all written in English(Transliterated). It doesn't matter whether the words are of French, Italian, Spanish, Chinese etc.. langaueg. It will all be detected as English because it's written by using the character sets of English language.

So Polyglot is only useful for the languages which uses Non-Latin characters in it like Greek, Russian, Arabic or Chinese.

That is why you got Chinese language as well in below case, Confidence is low because very few characters are in Chinese and more are Latin characters:

> China (simplified Chinese: 中国; traditional Chinese: 中國),
>
> name: English     code: en       confidence:  71.0 read bytes:   887
> name: Chinese     code: zh_Hant  confidence:  11.0 read bytes:  1755
> name: un          code: un       confidence:   0.0 read bytes:     0